# Get user properties from azure AD using Graph API

Tags: java, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Graph API to import users from Azure AD. Before getting the user list I want to get all the properties available for a user. Is there any API I can use for that. Currently I calling the get all users rest service itself and getting the keys from the first user object. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all metadata from [https://graph.windows.net/"YourTenantId"/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User](https://graph.windows.net/%3Ctenant%3E/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User)

Look for the `<EntityType Name="User" ...` tag.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing which property I can consider as unique username ? My application is expecting a unique email id as username. Here I get property **mail** as null sometimes and there is one more **userPrincipalName** property which is not same as what we enter as username while adding a user in AD. I would like to get the username which we enter while adding a user.

Comment: The **userPrincipalName** is what you can consider a username. If it is not the same as what you enter, then you probably need to change the user's principal domain.  
If you need a unique never-changing ID, you should use **objectId**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a user object is well defined.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

Comment: Am I supposed to hard code these properties? Is it possible to add new properties for user from Azure AD? If so how will I get that new property?